# Indented footnotes in KOMA-Script

Tags: footnotes, koma-script

I would like to set up my footnotes using a plain indented style, with the footnote marker placed in the text after an indent:

```
   1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet et uiuit.
   2. Footnote
```

The trouble is that KOMA-Script sets the footnote marker in a right-justified box. This is fine for smaller numbers, but when one gets into double digits, the indent becomes inconsistent:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\deffootnote[2em]{0em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark.\ }

\begin{document}

\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

Is there a setting somewhere that I am missing to have KOMA-Script place the footnote marker inline without the box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can patch `\deffootnote` to replace the `\hbox to \z@`, that is used for the footnote number, by a simple `\hbox` (of its natural width):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\deffootnote}{\hbox to \z@}{\hbox}{}{\undefined}
\makeatother

\deffootnote[2em]{0em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark.\ }

\begin{document}

\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}\addtocounter{footnote}{99} \blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

[image: two footnotes]

With this patch, the optional argument minus the second argument is the indent. This may be somehow strange, but it works (as long, as you do not switch to compatibility with versions < 3.22).

Comment: That's absolutely perfect – thank you very much!